# Python - Why is my conversion of RGB to YDbDr so pixelated?

Tags: numpy, opencv, kornia

So I have this original image:

[image: Original]

Then I have it's [YDbDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YDbDr) conversion:

[image]

it's separated by red, blue and green channels which I know aren't equivalent to YDbDr, but should give a good general gauge on whether the channels have been converted correctly. As you can see Db and Dr equivalently are heavily pixelated when they shouldn't be.

Here's the code:

```
def RGB_to_YDbDr(obs_RGB):
    r = obs_RGB[:, 0]
    g = obs_RGB[:, 1]
    b = obs_RGB[:, 2]

    y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
    db = -0.450 * r + -0.883 * g + 1.333 * b
    dr = -1.333 * r + 1.116 * g + 0.217 * b

    return torch.stack([y, db, dr], -3)
```

I followed [Kornia](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kornia/color/ycbcr.html#rgb_to_ycbcr)  augmentation library's code for RGB to YCbCr to implement RGB to YDbDr. What did I do wrong? Why does Db and Dr look so pixelated? The input images are 100 x 100.

Note:
I tried `kornia.color.rgb_to_ycbcr` and got this:
[image]
Also seems very heavily pixelated

Comment: Has your test image been compressed? Can you attach it?

Comment: @stateMachine no it shouldn't be compressed the output size is still 100 x 100. How can I attach it?

Comment: To attach it, just edit the question and use attach picture you have used to attach the plots.

Comment: I suggest you to include also the code you use for loading the data.

Comment: it's definitely compressed. @stateMachine's hunch is absolutely correct and "shouldn't" should not be taken at face value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Look closely. Your source image is compressed already. What you see is the "chroma subsampling" that is done by image compression. You see blocks of color distortion.

That is exactly what you see in your color (chroma) planes.

Nooo this has nothing to do with plotting or anything. Your source image is compressed. You can only fix that if you have an uncompressed source image, or one that isn't so severely compressed.

Comment: so the compression is done by a simulator. I unfortunately don't have the ability to get the original image unless I do some monkey patching I presume.

Comment: you could ask it to make larger pictures, and if you need them to be 100x100, shrink them yourself and save with better compression.

Comment: unfortunately I need the image to be 100x100. Perhaps I could use your suggestion if there was a better image compression algorithm than what the simulator is using. Can you suggest one?

Comment: uh.... I don't understand why you have that question. just use JPEG, but with better quality factor. or use png. or use plain bitmaps.

Comment: the reason I ask is because the simulator doesn't generate the images as image files, it generates it as numpy arrays.